# (TexLive) after upgrade tex cannot see my fonts

Tags: fonts, texlive

I upgraded from TexLive 2013 to 2015, now tex cannot see the fonts installed in `/usr/share/fonts/`.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Which operating system are you on?

Comment: I'm using Linux.  Somehow I solved the problem by re-installing fonts, but I can't recall the specific steps.  It's kind of frustrating.